# MSP430FR5994 Launchpad UART Reference Design Not Working

Tags: uart, msp430, firmware, texas-instruments

I'm developing an ADC data acquisition application using the MSP430FR5994 Launchpad and I need to send received data to the PC using the ez-fet backchannel UART (eusci_a0_uart). As an initial step, I've tested a few different TI MSP430FR5994 UART echo reference designs as well as a separate known working UART echo application on the Launchpad. The reference designs (as well as the separate application) are fairly straightforward and I haven't made any modifications, but I haven't been able to achieve any serial communication at all. I know I'm establishing the connection from the PC correctly using PuTTy and I'm using designs that should work, so I'm not sure what's causing this problem (The Launchpad is recognized in device manager, I can establish a connection, but the actual echo doesn't work (meaning I  can't transmit anything from PC and nothing is received)). Is there some sort of ez-fet UART bring up that I've completely missed? Any ideas at all are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that the PuTTy connection is correct, when it does not work? Which of the two COM ports did you use? How did you configure it?

Answer (score 1):

I've written two programs in code composer studio for MSP430G2 Launchpad,
The first one is just a short program that displays the given text in the code to the serial output in 19200 baud.
The second one is reading a dht11 sensor periodically and outputting the values to the serial monitor.
https://github.com/selimg76/microcontroller/blob/master/msp430serialmonitor
https://github.com/selimg76/microcontroller/blob/master/MSP430_DHT11_Sensor

And I tried to explain it in the following videos:

https://youtu.be/Fzf8q6fgxfQ

https://youtu.be/Hid_jB_Dy-A

I hope these will be useful for you, if you have questions about the code, please let me know.